# Google Chrome generates an <object> tag near my <video> tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have an  tag containing both a mp4 and a ogv file. Video plays nicely in most computers and browsers. But in some specific cases Google Chrome creates a  tag and renders it as a black box near th video. I can't style this box with css, so I'm not able to hide it.
The new  tag comes with the id="RPHTML5video_Plugin_0". Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: your description is vague, can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

In my Google Chrome occurs the same. I have removed this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\Real\RealPlayer\BrowserRecordPlugin\Chrome
```

Now it works perfectly, but I don't now how resolve this issue if my client has it. To delete the RPHTML5Video < div> with javascript is not a solution because the element appears continously.